# DIV Click Download Audio File

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, mp3

I have this audio MP3 file and I want to have it downloaded when the user clicks a DIV using JavaScript/JQuery.

```
$("#button").live("click",function(){
    // initiate download
});
```

Any help whatsoever would be appreciated. I can't seem to find anything on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: [`.live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, use [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: use the download attrib of <a> tags to to force a download. you can call A.click() from your button click handler, provided the href of the <a> is set to the mp3 and download is set to the desired file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe answer is one way to do it, but often times the MP3 will simply play inside the iframe, so if you don't want to bother with any server side work, and the MP3s are hosted by you (at least in Firefox, this isn't required in Chrome), you can use the download attribute of the a element.

```
<a href="audio.MP3" download="DownloadedFilenameHere.mp3">Download</a>
```

If you really need it to be a DIV, you can either encase the div in the a element or use a Javascript workaround like this one. One nice advantage to a JS solution is you can do this for multiple files at once.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "audio.MP3";
link.setAttribute('download', "DownloadedFilenameHere.mp3");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(link);
// Firefox
if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initEvent("click", true, true);
    link.dispatchEvent(event);
}
// IE
else if (link.click) {
    link.click();
}
link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

If you want this for multiple downloads, just use window.setInterval and use an interval of 500 milliseconds. Using a for loop won't work because for one reason or another Firefox isn't able to handle that many downloads at once, and you must space it out instead.

Comment: Nice solution! Browser support's [not so good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download), but +1.

Comment: you can just call link.click(), not sure why everyone uses the overly-complex fake events...

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara although at least if it doesn't work the user will be redirected to the file, rather than the sound playing from an invisible iframe without the user being able to stop it.

Comment: @dandavis as far as my research went, .click() is an IE function and, although other browsers eventually supported it, I still prefer to use the proper function native to that browser. You're right, however. In our modern day, you can simply remove the Firefox section, as Firefox has now supported IE's function.

Comment: anything that supports a[download] will support click(), which i think worked in firefox2... after making http://danml.com/download.html, i found all sorts of those potential support holes that weren't actual device holes because of the modern requirements of the other moving parts...

Comment: Yes, but this way even if the download attribute doesn't work at least the user will be redirected to the MP3 file to save it for themselves. On a seperate note, the user can also right-click>Save Target As using this method

Comment: Only with set download attribute works for me. `<a href="audio.mp3" download> Download </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `iframe` with the `src` set to your MP3.

That's only half the solution though. To ensure the user is prompted to download the file, rather than just get a player, you will need to set the following header through your server configuration (i.e.e mod_headers) or by a script (i.e. PHP).

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=somefilename.mp3;
```

**Example:**

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){
    $("<iframe />")
        .css({width:0,height:0})
        .attr("src", "URL_TO_MP3")
        .appendTo("body");
});
```

Comment: actually, it's the content-disposition header that matters, navigating to an mp3 often displays a player...